# Paypal REST API: How can I get authenticated users email/name without using the Identity API?

Tags: php, authentication, paypal

So it seems like https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/v1/ only works if you're using Connect with Paypal API. This isn't an option at the moment. I have a Paypal widget within my dashboard and users can add multiple accounts. I need an email or name to help my users distinguish this account from their others. I tried using /userinfo but I only received the user_id property.

Is there something I can do differently to get email/name from this endpoint or is there somewhere else I can get this data? This workflow is best for users but if needed I can have them manually enter the info on my application

Comment: "I have a Paypal widget within my dashboard and users can add multiple accounts."  Please, elaborate.  What is this widget and what does it do. Are you calling PayPal APIs? What is returned to you already?

Comment: @PrestonPHX This widget was previously using the SOAP API. I am creating a new widget for Paypal using the REST API. This widget will pull in recent invoices and other data to view metrics on a graph. There is a configuration screen and on that one of the fields is for the Paypal account. When they add their account I want to give it a name to display in case they add another account. With most integrations I can pull this data in through API instead of requesting it from user

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question, but if you want to use a REST API to authenticate a user and get their information, it should be Connect with PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was making sure all permissions per enabled and I added my return URL. I was doing this to setup connect with paypal button but then tried a postman request and realized I could now get all user info needed